# React Router behaving differently at localhost and Heroku

Tags: javascript, reactjs, heroku, react-router

I am building a React-based website, started with `create-react-app` and using react-router-dom`. This is my structure:

#### index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import './index.css';

import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

#### App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

import reducers from './reducers';

import Menu from './components/Menu';

import Blog from './components/Blog';
import Books from './components/Books';
import Contact from './components/Contact';
import Curriculum from './components/Curriculum';
import Lectures from './components/Lectures';
import MainPage from './components/MainPage';
import Mathematics from './components/Mathematics';
import SocialNetworks from './components/SocialNetworks';
import Software from './components/Software';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={createStore(reducers)}>
        <div className="contents">
            <div className="banner-top shadowed-text">
                <div className="my-name">
                    Ed de Almeida
                </div>
                <div className="my-professions">
                    Mathematician, Software Developer, Writer and Lecturer
                </div>
                <SocialNetworks />
            </div>
            <Menu />
            <div className="page-area">
                <BrowserRouter>
                    <div className="top-margin-area">
                        <Route exact path="/" component={MainPage} />
                        <Route path="/curriculum" component={Curriculum} />
                        <Route path="/math" component={Mathematics} />
                        <Route path="/software" component={Software} />
                        <Route path="/blog" component={Blog} />
                        <Route path="/books" component={Books} />
                        <Route path="/lectures" component={Lectures} />
                        <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />
                    </div>
                </BrowserRouter>
            </div>
        </div>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
};
```

When I run it in my local server it works perfectly well. I may navigate to all URLs defined in the routes and I see exactly what is is expected.

The trouble starts when I do my `git push heroku master`. Although it builds perfectly at Heroku, with no error messages, I  may only open the homepage ("/"). If I navigate to "/curriculum", for example, I get a `404 Not Found` error message.

### Important:

This is the Heroku URL: http://eddealmeida.herokuapp.com/

I am relatively new to React and this is my first time hosting React at Heroku. I created my Heroku app using this buildpack [here](https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack).

Am I missing something?

Oh, before I forget... When I run locally using `heroku local` it also works perfectly well. It is only there at Heroku which things go wrong!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [the documentation](https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack/blob/master/README.md#user-content-routing-clean-urls) of the buildpack you are using, you’ll need to configure the Heroku app for routing by creating a `static.json` file:

> React Router (not included) may easily use hash-based URLs like https://example.com/index.html#/users/me/edit. This is nice & easy when getting started with local development, but for a public app you probably want real URLs like https://example.com/users/me/edit.
>
> Create a static.json file to configure the web server for clean browserHistory with React Router v3 & BrowserRouter with v4:

```
{
  "root": "build/",
  "routes": {
    "/**": "index.html"
  }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. I hadn't noticed this fact when I read the documentation. It was a superficial reading, I confess.